# Django Model queries with relationships. How to do the right join

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Let's say I have 2 Models:

```
class Auction(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="seller")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Watchlist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_watchlist')
    auction = models.ForeignKey(Auction, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='auction_watchlist')
```

The view receives a request, creates a context variable with the auction objects the are:

1. associated with the user who made the request and
2. that have been added to the Watchlist Model,

sends it to the template.

I have set up my view to work like this:

```
@login_required
def watchlist(request): 
    watchlist_objects = Watchlist.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    auction_objects = Auction.objects.filter(auction_watchlist__in=watchlist_objects).all()
    context = {'watchlist_auctions': auction_objects}
    print(context)
    return render(request, "auctions/watchlist.html", context)
```

-I make the first query to get the list of items in the watchlist associate with the user.

-Then I use that to get another query from the Auction Model and I pass it to the template.

In the template I can access the attributes of Auction to display them. (title, author, and others that I did not include for simplicity)

The question is:
Is this the "right way? Is there a better way to access the attributes in Auction from the first Watchlist query?

It seems to me that I'm doing something overcomplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not that bad, considering that it will probably be executed as one query, because of the [lazy queryset evaluations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy). You can skip the `.all()` if you already have `.filter()`.

However, there is a more convenient way to do this, using [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).:

```
auction_objects = Auction.objects.filter(auction_watchlist__user_id=request.user.id)
```